# Javascript copying file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, yeoman

I'm using React for the time on a project in Yeoman and I have to admit I'm out of my depth.
I'm making a website and hosting it on localhost:3000 to test.
I want to be able to upload a file and then that file will be copied into the given directory.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Instance load Manager</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://fountainjs.io/assets/imgs/fountain.png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="moveFile()" />
    </div>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import {Hello} from './app/hello';
import {Upload} from './app/upload';

import './index.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Hello}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.moveFile(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Upload}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

upload.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Upload extends Component {
  moveFile() {
    const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    if (file) {
      //  getAsText(file);
      file.copy(`$decodeURI("C:\\Users\\I329968\\Documents\\") / $file.displayName`);
      return (
        <h2>{'Hello world!'}</h2>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine except the upload.js doesn't seem to do anything at all. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't define `render` method in that file, whenever we create any `component`, we need to define `render` method, that is the place from where `React` starts the creation the `ui`. try this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Upload extends Component {
  moveFile() {
    const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    if (file) {
      //  getAsText(file);
      file.copy(`$decodeURI("C:\\Users\\I329968\\Documents\\") / $file.displayName`);
      console.log('hello in move file', file);
    }
  }

  render(){
      return(
           <div>
              Hello in upload.js
              <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange={this.moveFile.bind(this)}/>
           </div>
      );
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Do these changes also:

*Remove these lines from `index.html` file and put that in `upload.js`:

```
<div id="header">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="moveFile()" />
</div>
```

*You forgot to include the `bundle.js` file in index.html

```
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
```

*Remove the these lines:

```
ReactDOM.moveFile(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Upload}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*Render `Upload` component on some different route, use this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Hello}/>
    <Route path="/upload" component={Upload}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Use these components:**

app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

export default class Upload extends Component {

  render(){
      return(
           <div>
              Hello in app.js
              <br/>
              <Link to='/upload'>Go to upload component</Link>
           </div>
      );
  }
}
```

upload.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Upload extends Component {
  moveFile() {
    const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    if (file) {
      //  getAsText(file);
     //file.copy(`$decodeURI("C:\\Users\\I329968\\Documents\\") / $file.displayName`);
      console.log('hello in move file', file);
    }
  }

  render(){
      return(
           <div>
              Hello in upload.js
              <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple onChange={this.moveFile.bind(this)}/>
           </div>
      );
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory, Link} from 'react-router';

import Upload from './upload';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/upload" component={Upload}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>View</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>   
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src = "bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this but it doesn't work. I'm not even seeing the added <h2>

Comment: Error: "JSX props must not use bind"

Comment: are you using any bind in app compnent ?

Comment: No, I don't think so - I honestly don't know what it is :(

Comment: use the code that i pasted it will work, as i tested it :) just run webpack and open the index.html. change the name of bundle.js file if you are saving with some different name.

Comment: Sorry if I'm bothering you but I am confused. I do not have a bundle.js? Only index.js and upload.js and hello.js - did you mean one of these? Also what is app.js? Or do you want me to create this file? Thank you again for your help, my friend! :)